# Clusterization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sas, cluster-analysis

I have problem with clusterization of clients.

I have a dataset with columns such as `name`, `address`, `email`, `phone`, etc. (in a example `A`,`B`,`C`). Each row has unique identifier (`ID`). I need to assign `CLUSTER_ID` (`X`) to each row. In one cluster all rows have one or more the same attributes as other rows. So clients with `ID=1,2,3` have the same `A` attribute and clients with `ID=3,10` have the same `B` attribute then `ID=1,2,3,10` should be in the same cluster.

How can I solve this problem using SQL? 
If it's not possible how to write the algorithm (pseudocode)?
The performance is very important, because the dataset contains milions of rows.

Sample Input:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   A1  B3  C1
2   A1  B2  C5
3   A1  B10 C10
4   A2  B1  C5
5   A2  B8  C1
6   A3  B1  C4
7   A4  B6  C3
8   A4  B3  C5
9   A5  B7  C2
10  A6  B10 C3
11  A8  B5  C4
```

Sample Output:

```
ID  A   B   C   X
1   A1  B3  C1  1
2   A1  B2  C5  1
3   A1  B10 C10 1
4   A2  B1  C5  1
5   A2  B8  C1  1
6   A3  B1  C4  1
7   A4  B6  C3  1
8   A4  B3  C5  1
9   A5  B7  C2  2
10  A6  B10 C3  1
11  A8  B5  C4  1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a graph-walking problem which can be solved using recursive CTEs (which not all databases support).  However, the exact syntax depends on your database, so you should tag the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using SAS, so probably I need step by step algorithm rather than specific DB syntax.

Comment: So an ID can't be in more than 1 cluster X?

Comment: Yes, each ID should be in one cluster.

Comment: How much RAM do you have ? How many million rows ? Can the data set be loaded into RAM with `SASFILE BIG_HAVE` ?  This [array based example](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/#superset) might be adapted to your data.

Comment: Looks like you are just trying to build the connected sub-graphs of the graph that your starting data represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is by repeating updates for the empty X.

Start with cluster_id 1. 
F.e. by using a variable.

```
SET @CurrentClusterID = 1
```

Take the top 1 record, and update it's X to 1.

Now loop an update for all records with an empty X, 
and that can be linked to a record with X = 1 and that has the same A or B or C

*Disclaimer:

  The statement will vary depending on the RDBMS.

  This is just intended as pseudo-code.*

```
WHILE (<<some check to see if there were records updated>>) 
BEGIN
  UPDATE yourtable t
  SET t.X = @CurrentClusterID
  WHERE t.X IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM yourtable d 
      WHERE d.X =  @CurrentClusterID
        AND (d.A = t.A OR d.B = t.B OR d.C = t.C)
  );
END
```

Loop that till it updates 0 records.

Now repeat the method for the other clusters, till there are no more empty X in the table.

> 1) Increase the @CurrentClusterID by 1
>    2) Update the next top 1 record with an empty X to the new @CurrentClusterID
>    3) Loop the update till no-more updates were done.

An example test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4922e5d7681589ff1e74e3715455528)* for MS Sql Server.

Comment: You could adopt this to work with SAS by doing it inside a macro.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just implemented what you said and this algorithm doesn't give the best solution. For the sample input I mentioned, your method creates 4 clusters, but it should be only 2.

Comment: @RobertSoszyński  Look at the example I added in the answer. It works for that sample.

Comment: Btw, I didn't say it explicitly, but of course even going to the next @CurrentClusterID for the next record that has an empty X can be looped instead of doing that manually. A loop till no X is left empty in the table.